# SQL Server - Is my database being queried over linked server?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

Is there a way to know if a specific database on my SQL Server instance is being queried over linked server?

Answer (score 10):

No.  A linked server is just some other SQL Server making a connection to your SQL Server.  There's no way to reliably identify these connections.

Comment: I thought that perhaps investigating query text on `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` because they would appear as `linkedservername.databasename.schemaname.tablename`

Comment: That would appear on the server containing the linked server destination and processing the query.  On the target of the linked server you would not see the `linkedservernname`.  And not all linked server access uses 4-part names anyway.

Answer (score 10):

There is one possible way, it is to look at sessions/connections, and guess by session's properties that this session is coming from unusual source:

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions s
    join sys.dm_exec_connections c on 
    s.session_id = c.session_id
```

- host_name = this is server name, you can find out if there's a SQL Server installed on it
- client_interface_name = 'OLEDB'
- program_name = 'Microsoft SQL Server'
- client_net_address = this is IP address, will hint you to a server which might have SQL Server installed

Especially when you know very well, from which IP addresses and hosts usual connections / sessions (your apps or users) are coming from, you will be able to distinct anything that is suspicious

Then join the `sys.dm_exec_requests` and `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` to get the query that session is executing. The query can be like

```
SELECT ... FROM "DB"."dbo"."Table" "Tbl1002"
```

This will hint you to a database.

Again, I am not saying this will help in 100% cases, but might help you to identify what you are looking for